Open docx Document with word via SSH onto Windows host
I'm trying to open a word document on a windows host via OpenSSH connection.
Connecting to the host works.
Running the following powershell commands
$word.Visible = $false    
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($file.Fullname) 
$null -ne $doc

directly on the windows host works - $doc is not null
but when executing in a powershell via ssh connection
it doesn't work - $doc is null but no error message is diplayed - $error is empty
I tried using psexec with no success.
ssh user@172.18.0.2 "psexec -i 1 -d powershell.exe 'opendoc.ps1'"
